# Wordpress Sidebar fallen below content

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

my site is http://goo.gl/T5XTOf

It's a mystique wordpress site and the sidebar has fallen below the main content. When I tried to change the logo image in theme options, it didn't work, so I changed it at the webhost level. I changed the current logo image to a smaller image, the sidebar fell below the main content on all pages and posts.

I changed the logo back to the previous one (Current one) but it didn't solve the issue. So I changed the default template on all the pages to 2 columns with left sidebar and this solved the issue with pages. However, the posts remained the same. I use the post pages for product pages using a shopping cart plugin.

So since the posts did not have options to change the template, I tried using a simple posts template which allowed for several page templates to be chosen. But this did not change anything on the sidebar issue, even when I change the template to 2 columns with left sidebar.

Can anyone help with this? I tried looking over the answers on this forum but none seemed to work. I posted this issue on the theme's forum but have not received any replies for days now.

Comment: But where should it stand, than?

Comment: On the left side - check the sidebar on http://goo.gl/T5XTOf

Comment: On the main homepage and the other pages, the sidebar is okay, but it falls below the main content on the product pages.

Comment: This is happening because you don't have any width/styles set for the sidebar/content on those pages.

Comment: What does that mean? What file should I edit and with what code?

Comment: I have since removed the sidebar from all product pages so that it looks better. However, if anyone can still help with the original question, I will reinstate the sidebar. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again Redleaf. I tried your edit but it pushed the sidebar leftwards half out of view. Anyway, I have switched to another theme and the website looks better. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your stylesheet (appearance/editor/style.css):

```
#primary-content{
    max-width:650px;
    margin:20px;
}
#sidebar{
    width:220px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Redleaf. I tried your edit but it pushed the sidebar leftwards half out of view. Anyway, I have switched to another theme and the website looks better. Thanks for your help.